# Sending bytes in a string message and changing it back to string

Tags: python, string, sockets, encoding, byte

I am coding a P2P framework in python, it works just fine and I built a filesharing app with it. Only problem, is I can't figure out how to send binary type files (zip archive in this case), in the following code you can see in a compact way what I am doing through my framework when handling files.

```
f = open('hhh.zip', 'rb')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()

msg = 'REPLY 5 %s' % filedata
msg = msg.encode('utf-8')

# SENDING

# ...

# RECEIVING

msg = msg.decode('utf-8')
msgtype, msglen, msgdata = msg.split(maxsplit=2)

f = open('received_archive.zip', 'xb')
f.write(msgdata)
f.close()
```

I am using a message structure where I indicate the message type, the lenght of the message data and the actual data. That means I can't just send the bytes of the zip file, that would obviously work. What happens is that I get my data (the bytes of archive.zip) back as a string and I can't figure out how to convert it back to bytes so I can write the received file.

The error I get is the following:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 18, in <module>
    f.write(msgdata)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

The `filedata` is the following:
`b'PK\x03\x04\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00z\xbc7K\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x1c\x00hhhUT\t\x00\x03\xb8\xd3\xc6Y\xb8\xd3\xc6Yux\x0b\x00\x01\x04\xe8\x03\x00\x00\x04\xe8\x03\x00\x00PK\x01\x02\x1e\x03\n\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00z\xbc7K\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03\x00\x18\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\xb4\x81\x00\x00\x00\x00hhhUT\x05\x00\x03\xb8\xd3\xc6Yux\x0b\x00\x01\x04\xe8\x03\x00\x00\x04\xe8\x03\x00\x00PK\x05\x06\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00I\x00\x00\x00=\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00'`

The `msgdata` after decoding it (`bytes(msgdata, 'utf-8')`):
`b"b'PK\\x03\\x04\\n\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00z\\xbc7K\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x03\\x00\\x1c\\x00hhhUT\\t\\x00\\x03\\xb8\\xd3\\xc6Y\\xb8\\xd3\\xc6Yux\\x0b\\x00\\x01\\x04\\xe8\\x03\\x00\\x00\\x04\\xe8\\x03\\x00\\x00PK\\x01\\x02\\x1e\\x03\\n\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00z\\xbc7K\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x03\\x00\\x18\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\xb4\\x81\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00hhhUT\\x05\\x00\\x03\\xb8\\xd3\\xc6Yux\\x0b\\x00\\x01\\x04\\xe8\\x03\\x00\\x00\\x04\\xe8\\x03\\x00\\x00PK\\x05\\x06\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x01\\x00\\x01\\x00I\\x00\\x00\\x00=\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00'"`

And without decoding `msgdata` I am getting the first thing, but as a string, when trying to convert it back to bytes I am getting the second one.

Comment: Have you tried `bytes('msgdata', 'utf-8')`? I also always have problems with encoding.

Comment: No it doesn't work, look the post, I edited some precisions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bytes` and `str` representations of the same file are pretty much equivalent, with `bytes` representation being able to contain slightly more things than `str`, including non-unicode data.

There's no need to distinguish between file types if you want to send them over a network. You can just treat everything as `bytes`, read them in binary mode, send them as bytes (actually python 3 won't let anything else) and write them in binary mode - no data will be lost.

```
with open('hhh.zip', 'rb') as f:
    filedata = f.read()

msg = b'REPLY 5 %s' % filedata  # or equivalent if they still don't support % for bytes

# SENDING
# ...
# RECEIVING

msgtype, msglen, msgdata = msg.split(maxsplit=2)

with open('received_archive.zip', 'xb') as f:
    f.write(msgdata)
```

Moreover, it's kind of against logic to convert to unicode (`msg.encode('utf-8')`) something that is not a human-readable data at all.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the clarification, I'm quite new to networking.